# Destroy a process tree and free all memory allocated by it - linux- C

Tags: c, linux, process, malloc, free

If you know the pid of a process is there a way to destroy the hole process tree created from that process and free all the memory allocated by those processes ? I need to find a way to do that in a C program without having to go to each process of the tree.

so here is the code I made after reading Basile Starynkevitch very useful answer .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void proctreecreator(int count);

int main()
{
    int status,count;
    count = 0;
    pid_t pid,procapid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("main: fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if( setpgid(0,0) <0 ) perror( "main: setpgid" );
        proctreecreator(count);
        exit(1);
    }
    procapid=pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("main: fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("I will now destroy the process tree \n");
        kill(-procapid, SIGTERM);
        exit(0);
    }
    procapid = waitpid(procapid, &status, 0);
    if (procapid < 0) perror( "main: waitpid" );
    else printf("Process A and its tree are killed\n");
    pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0); 
    if (pid < 0) perror("main: waitpid");
    else printf("process B exited \n");
    return 0;
}

void proctreecreator(int count)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status,i;
    int *k = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *k=count;
    pid_t mypid=getpid();
    printf("process with pid : %d created in depth %d \n",mypid,count);
    if (count > 3) 
    {
        sleep(5);
        free(k);
        exit(0);
    } 
    else 
    {
        count++;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("proctreecreator: fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            proctreecreator(count);
            exit(1);
        }
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("proctreecreator: fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            proctreecreator(count);
            exit(1);
        }
        for (i=0; i<2; i++) 
        {
            pid = wait(&status);
            if (pid < 0) perror("proctreecreator: wait");
            else printf("process %d is now terminated",pid);            
        }
        free(k);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have some questions about how the programm works! When using kill(-procapid, SIGTERM); does it take constant time to destroy the process tree or does it depend on the size of the tree ?  Is all memory allocated with malloc free after kill(-procapid, SIGTERM); ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you will get better/more answers if you give more details, including whatever research or code you have tried so far.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask, and what is exactly the process tree you are considering....? Be specific!

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and the answer. I will read all the links you have written and then I will try to write the code to solve the problem and edit my question in order to post the code. As for the problem : At first in function main I will create using fork two children A and B . Child A is going to allocate memory using malloc and then it will create two children . Each of the children is going to do the same , allocate memory and create 2 children. At some point I want process B to destroy process A and the process tree that has A as root and free all allocated memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is terminated, all the [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) that it has used -including [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28programming%29) often [managed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management) by `malloc` & `free`, generally thru [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) etc...- is released (except for [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)).

The [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for (forcibly) terminating some other process is [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), which exactly sends a [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) to a process (or a process group). Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). If all the processes in your process tree belongs to the same [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) (see [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) ...) you just need to `kill` that process group. See also [killpg(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html).

You should first `kill` with `SIGTERM`. This gives the opportunity for well behaved programs (like many [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS) servers) to handle that signal appropriately (e.g. releasing resources, cleaning up, etc...). A second later, you could `kill` with `SIGQUIT`. At last, you could send the `SIGKILL` signal which cannot be caught and will always terminate processes.

Read also about sessions and [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html) (and [setpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) for process groups) and controlling terminal. See also the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) page and the [job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) wikipage.

Notice that some processing could still continue. Imagine that some of your processes is [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) [batch(1)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) i.e. `/usr/bin/batch`  (or `ssh`)

So your first program forks some `A`; make it call `setpgid(0,0)` (see [setpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) for details). Of course, your first program needs to keep the pid of `A` (returned by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)), let us suppose it is in `pid_t pid_of_A`; then you'll need to later `kill(-pid_of_A, SIGTERM)` and at last `waitpid(pid_of_A, &status_of_A, 0)`  (see [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)...).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

---

You have edited your question by adding:

> have some questions about how the program works! When using `kill(-procapid, SIGTERM)`; does it take constant time to destroy the process tree or does it depend on the size of the tree ?

This really should have been another question. The theoretical complexity of `kill` when killing a process group should not bother you in practice. The reason is that in practice you don't have a lot of (running) processes; you only want -unless you are running on a multi-million dollar [supercomputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer)- to have a few dozen of running processes (otherwise your entire system and machine would be overloaded and begin [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)). So the actual complexity of killing a process tree does not matter much, since in practice your process tree would have only a few dozen running processes (and a few hundred processes in total, most of them being idle).

You also ask

> Is all memory allocated with malloc free after `kill(-procapid, SIGTERM);` ?

Read more about [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), the [fork system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), [fork bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Please understand that each process uses [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and has its own [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), and `malloc` uses e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to change the address space of the running process (only).

When a process terminates, its entire address space is deleted by the kernel. This is not immediately related to `kill(`... `SIGTERM)` because some processes will catch `SIGTERM` to do useful cleanup. (In other words, sending `SIGTERM` to some process won't always *immmediately* terminate it).

[Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) is explaining that in details, much better than I have to do.

And yes, creating a process (with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)), terminating a process (because of some terminating [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) or because it has gently [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html)-ed), replacing the running program with another one in a process (with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) ...), and changing the address space of a running process (with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) often used by `malloc`...) are complex and expensive operations, but the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is doing them quite well.

Processes are quite expansive resources, so you should not have a big lot of them. Hence [asymptotic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_complexity) is not the right concept to reason about them. You want to have "few" of them (and what "few" means depend upon your particular system and hardware). Right now my i3770K Linux/Debian desktop (with 16Gbytes RAM) has 238 processes, most of them being idle (run `ps auxw` in a terminal to find out), only a few are running. Recent Linux kernels have an efficient [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29), often an [O(1) scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%281%29_scheduler).

<sup>Linux is rumored to be quite good at managing processes, and creating a process on Linux is believed to be faster than on Windows.</sup>